# How to use pypy

Tags: python, pypy

I have just installed pypy (pypy3.5-v7.0.0-win32.zip from https://bitbucket.org/pypy/pypy/downloads/) to run my code faster and now I don't know how to use it for my python 3.5.0 program. I sow this [Using PyPy to run a Python program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25947628/using-pypy-to-run-a-python-program), but I didn't manage to understand exactly.

Comment: `pypy your_file.py`

Comment: This should be a file name?

Answer (score 0):

Go to your source folder where you wrote your python code.
Click on the file explorer navigation bar.
Delete what it says and type cmd to open the command prompt.
In the command prompt type: pypy3 **yourfile.py**

If you get an error make sure your pypy is in your environment variable window.
To do that in your search, type "Edit environment variables" and open it.
Where it says "Path", double click on it, a new window appears.
Click new and paste the location where you installed pypy.
Then click OK.